# Calculate the area of a sector of a circle? [My answer is different to the textbook answer, who is correct?]

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, circles, solution-verification, area

Ok, so the link attached shows my answer with working out, the textbook's answer and the question. If someone could explain if my answer is correct or if the textbook's answer is correct?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9rMEP.jpg

thanks

Comment: As far as I can tell, your answer is correct.

Comment: Nothing wrong with your answer. Bad way of presenting a question. It's not even clear if that $7.8$ is meant to be the diameter or a radius, for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answers differ by a 
factor of $\pi$.

Looks like when 
they computed the answer
they forgot to
multiply by $\pi$.